# Changing stages of the EmPubLite project in Eclipse

Tags: android, commonsware

Using the 3.8 book I had my Eclipse EmPubLite project at the "Fragments" level (T9).  Upon obtaining the 4.0 book, I want to regress back to T5-Progress but I don't know how to do that and can't see any instructions in the book on how to go back and forth to the various stages using Eclipse.

I tried replacing /src and /res contents outside of eclipse but upon loading the project back into Eclipse I got errors saying that the java source file could not be read.

Is there an easy and proper way in which to accomplish this?
Thanks,
Gary Blakely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to regress back to T5-Progress but I don't know how to do that

The only way to "regress" is to delete the current project in Eclipse, then import the project from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus) at the point you wish to start. You can import a project via File > Import from the Eclipse main menu. You will find `EmPubLite/T4-Progress` in the repository -- you can either clone the repo or click the ZIP button on the repo's main page to download the contents as a ZIP file.